# Flutter - Keyboard is not displayed after first use of the form

Tags: forms, flutter

I'm working on a small project with Flutter. I have a screen with two states: or it displays a list of object from a SQLite database, or it shows a form to add a new object.
The code works well to add one (and only one) object. After insertion, it goes back to the list of object, including the inserted one. However, when I go again on the form to add an object, the keyboard does not show up when I put the focus on the field.

I have tried to reset the form, but it does not change anything.

Here is my code:

```
//Screen to display list of objects
class objectInventory extends StatefulWidget {
  _objectInventoryState createState() => _objectInventoryState();
}

class _objectInventoryState extends State<objectInventory> {
  String _state = "inventory"; // inventory, or add

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_state == "add") {
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      MyObject _insertedObject = new MyObject();
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Add a new object")),
        body: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Insert object name"),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please insert a value';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) => _insertedObject.objectName = value,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      _formKey.currentState.save();

                      //Generate uuid of the object
                      _insertedObject.uuid = Uuid().v4();

                      insertObject(_insertedObject).then((value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _state = "inventory";
                        });
                      });

                      /* Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/objectDetails',
                        arguments: {
                          'id': myObjectList.indexOf(_insertedObject)
                        }); */
                    }
                  },
                )
              ],
            )),
      );
    } else {
      //Affichage de l'inventaire
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('The Safe'), actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.list),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {});
              })
        ]),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getObjects(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
              debugPrint(snapshot.connectionState.toString());
              //Check the state of the data fetching
              if (snapshot.connectionState == "waiting") {
                return Center(
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                        child: Align(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter)));
              }
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text("No data available");
              }
              myObjectList = snapshot.data;
              return _buildObjectList();
            }),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _state = "add";
              });
            },
            label: Text('Add a new object'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
      );
    }
  }

  _buildObjectList() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: myObjectList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(myObjectList[i].objectName),
            //subtitle: Text(myObjectList[i].category),
            trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/objectDetails',
                      arguments: {'id': i});
                }),
          );
        });
  }
} // End of _objectInventoryState
```

Thank you

Comment: try this  " FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());" instead of this " FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();" and tell me the result

Comment: It works for the explained use case. However, it changed another behaviour: if I loose the focus, or click on the "enter" button in the keyboard, the field is emptied and I can't get the focus back.

Comment: ok then keep this change, but in addition try to ddefine a field which is a FocusNode and assign it to your textfield (initialize it in initState() and dispose it in dispose()) and try if it is fixed, sorry for trying to solve this in comments as it is hard to reproduce your code for now

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying helping me. However, I'm unsure when to include the initState and dispose functions.

Comment: these are methods of `State` class, you override them and put your code there, and did the comment abbove work for you? If yes tell me to post an answer

Comment: I think it would be best to post an answer, so that I can be sure that I implement it well. I'm unsure what you mean by "defining a field which is a FocusNode...". Thank you for your patience. As soon as it's posted, I'll try and let you know.